# Do you get all your attacks if you ready an Attack Action?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, readied-action, reactions

Say I have a fighter who has three attacks and uses ready action/hold action to "Attack the next person to come through that door". If someone comes through the door, does he get his reaction to get three attacks then on his regular initiative when his turn comes around make his normal three attacks for that round as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get only one attack when using a readied action to attack.

Note that the feature Extra attacks specifies (emphasis mine):

> whenever you take the Attack action **on your turn**.

You still get to do your normal 3 attacks on your next turn though.

Answer (score 6):

## You get one attack from a Readied Attack action

Based on Jeremy Crawford's [ruling](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/01/24/extra-attack-ready/):

> **Koontz** *@Koontz*
>
> *@JeremyECrawford*. A player with multi attack readies an attack, do they get all attacks on the trigger or just one
>
> ---
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** *@JeremyECrawford*
>
> *@Koontz* If you mean the Extra Attack feature, the extra attacks happen only on your turn.

This is because Extra Attacks need you to:

1. Use the Attack action
2. Do it on your turn

When you ready an attack, you are:

1. Using the Ready action
2. Attacking outside your turn

And so Extra Attack doesn't apply, and you only get one attack.